# What makes the use of transition(myComponent) fail in this React 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I am now working on adding **transitions between routes** (pages) with the help of **Framer Motion**.

For this purpose, I have added a `transition.js` file in `/src`, with the following content:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  return () => {
    <>
      <OgComponent />

      <motion.div
      className="slide-in"
      initial={{ opacity: 0, x: '-100px' }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.3 } }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.3 } }}
    >
      <motion.div />
    </>
  }
}

export default transition;
```

I import the above `transition` in the app's components with `import transition from '../../transition'` and wrap the exported component in it. See the Movielist component as an example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import Moviecard from '../Moviecard/Moviecard';
import transition from '../../transition';

function Movielist({ page_title, listMovies }) {

    const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const location = useLocation();
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

    const getMovies = async () => {
        const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/movie/${listMovies}`, {
            params: {
                api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
            }
        });

        setMovies(results);
    }

    const displayMovies = () => {
        return movies.map(movie => (
            <Moviecard
                key={movie.id}
                movie={movie}
            />
        ))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies();
    }, [location])

    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="page-title">{ page_title }</h1>
            <div className="row movie-list">
                { displayMovies() }
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default transition(Movielist);
```

In App.js I have "normal" routing:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Topbar from './components/Topbar/Topbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Movielist from './components/Movielist/Movielist';
import Moviedetails from './components/Moviedetails/Moviedetails';
import Actordetails from './components/Actordetails/Actordetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Topbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Movielist page_title="Now playing" listMovies="now_playing" />} />
          <Route path="/top-rated" element={<Movielist page_title="Top rated" listMovies="top_rated" />} />
          <Route path="/movie/:id" element={<Moviedetails />} />
          <Route path="/actor/:id" element={<Actordetails />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Sandbox

There is a sandbox with the code **[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-tu-6ycvdd?file=/src/components/Actordetails/Actordetails.jsx)**.

#### The problem

Changing `export default myComponent` to `export default transition(myComponent)` makes the component **fail to render**.

#### EDIT

Doing this...

```
const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  return () => (
    <>
      <OgComponent />

      <motion.div
        className="slide-in"
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 100, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

throws this **error**:

> Request failed with status code 404 AxiosError: Request failed with
> status code 404
> at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:63343:12)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62034:66)

*Before* trying to add smooth page transitions, it all *worked fine*.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: Open your browser tools (Ctrl+Shift+i on Firefox), go to the 'Network' tab, look for the failing request, what do you read?

Comment: @raaaahman The failing request is `undefined?api_key=myapykeyblacfewf`.  This only happends if I do `export default transition(Movielist)` instead of `export default Movielist`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you want (and it looks like this is what you were trying to do, so good job!) is to create a `Higher Order Component` that wraps your page component in the `motion.div` from `framer motion` so it can transition your component for you.

Try changing your `transition` code to this:

```
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export const withTransition = (TransitioningComponent) => {
  class WithTransition extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <motion.div
          className="slide-in"
          initial={{ opacity: 0, x: '-100px' }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.3 } }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
        >
          <TransitioningComponent {...this.props} />
        </motion.div>
      );
    }
  }

  WithTransition.displayName = `WithTransition(${
    TransitioningComponent.displayName || TransitioningComponent.name
  })`;

  return WithTransition;
};
```

Then you can call it by passing your page component as the `TransitioningComponent` arg to `withTransition` and exporting that from your jsx file.

```
// Movielist.jsx line 41
export default withTransition(Movielist);
```

Check out the working code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-with-transition-answer-gfrt3g)

Here's a gif of it in action

[image: page transition gif]

The `404` errors you keep getting from axios are due to expired API keys stored in the codesandbox `.env` file. I reckon the queries are failing due to a 403 - Access Denied response. I didn't check, but this makes the most sense to me. I commented out some of the axios calls so you can see the transition working.

I hope this answer has helped!

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because the function returned from the `transition` function does not render a component; it returns `undefined` instead.

```js
const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  // the function below does not return the component
  return () => {
    <>
      <OgComponent />
      ...
    </>
  }
}
```

To fix this, you can either remove the curly braces or define an explicit return for the inner function:

*explicit return*

```js
const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  return () => {
    return (
      <>
        <OgComponent />

        <motion.div
          className="slide-in"
          initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 100, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
        />
        <motion.div />
      </>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: I did the above, but I get a 404 error from Axios.

Comment: The `404` means that the REST API (_https://api.themoviedb.org/3_) has an issue and is not related to the rendering of the `transition` component. I'll suggest testing the component rendering with a different API endpoint.

Comment: The `Moviedetails` component is rendered correctly, but not the `Movielist` component.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in a tool like codepen or codesandbox?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the issue on codesandbox. Can you install dependencies and run the _Stackblitz_? Please share the any errors that are logged when you run the _Stackblitz_ with the solution.

Comment: There is a sandbox with the code **[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-tu-6ycvdd?file=/src/components/Actordetails/Actordetails.jsx)**.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say @dewaun-ayers' answer is correct. However, you don't have to rewrite your code as class component if you don't want to.

The missing part in OP's code is that the props from the Higher-Order Component `transition` (`withTransition` will be a more idiomatic naming convention, like pointed out by @dewaun-ayers), **are not passed** to the First-Order component.

So, this should fix it *as well*:

```js
const withTransition = (OgComponent) => {
  return (props) => (
    <motion.div
      className="slide-in"
      initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 100, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
    >
      <OgComponent {...props} />
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the arrow function in transition.js. The correct way to return the JSX is by using parentheses. Fix it like this:

```
const transition = (OgComponent) => {
  return () => (
    <>
      <OgComponent />

      <motion.div
        className="slide-in"
        initial={{ opacity: 0, x: '-100px' }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.3 } }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default transition;
```

This should resolve the issue and allow the component to render correctly.

Comment: I did that and the **Movielist** component fails to render, with a `Request failed with status code 404` error. Before trying to add transitions, it all worked fine.

Comment: 10 answers, some of them lengthy, with an average interval of less than 11 minutes looks like the typical [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) workflow. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785242/can-we-control-js-with-the-help-of-css-properties-is-that-possible/76785504#76785504) had the slip-up *"my last update in September 2021"*.